# Extjs4 - Ext.grid.Panel not updated with data inserted into Ext.data.Store using loadData function

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a listener defined on çhange event for an item filefield in a Panel. Using loadData method, on the Store with id **documentGridStore**, I am able to insert data into the store (debugger shows store updated) and count printed below correctly gets updated each time. But, the Panel is not getting updated no matter what I do.

Please suggest what is wrong/missing here. I have provided most of the relevant code.

```
Ext.define('uploadPaperDocumentDialogPanel', {
extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
...,
items: [{
            xtype: 'combobox',
            name: 'documentType',
            id: 'docTypeId',
            fieldLabel: getText('label.document.type'),
            emptyText: getText('label.select.type'),
            store: 'docTypeStore',
            displayField: 'key',
            valueField: 'value',
            allowBlank : false,
            selectOnFocus : true,
            typeAhead: true,
            forceSelection : true,
            queryMode:'local',
            width: 400
        },
        {
            xtype:'filefield',
            buttonText: 'Browse',
            msgTarget: 'qtip',
            name:'files[]',
            id:'fileId',
            allowBlank:false,
            style: "padding-left: 5px;padding-right: 20px",
            width: 275,
            listeners: {
                change: function(fld, value){
                    var files = fld.fileInputEl.dom.files;
                    var names = [];
                    if(files){
                        names.push({"documentType": Ext.getCmp('docTypeId').getValue() , "fileName": files[0].name});
                        Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('documentGridStore').loadData(names, true);
                        console.log(Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('documentGridStore').getCount());
                    }
                
                }
            },
            uploadDocumentGrid
        }]
});

Ext.define('DocumentGridModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields:[
             {name : 'documentType' , type : 'string'}
            ,{name : 'fileName',type : 'string'}
         ]
});

var UploadDocumentStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'DocumentGridModel',
    storeId:'documentGridStore',
    data:[]
    
});
    
var uploadDocumentGrid = Ext.define('DocumentGrid', {
    extend:'Ext.grid.Panel'
    ,alias:'widget.documentGridId',
    width: 400,
    border:true,
    bodyPadding: 0,  
    title: 'Documents to be uploaded',
    id:'documentGridId',
    iconCls: 'icon-stipNote',
    columnLines: true     
    ,store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('uploadDocumentGridStore')
    ,initComponent : function() {
  
    this.columns= [
                    {
                         header : 'Document Type',
                         id : 'documentType',
                         dataIndex : 'doctype',
                         flex:1,
                         align:"left",
                         editable : false,
                        sortable: false,
                        hideable: false,
                        resizable: false,
                   }, {
                        header : 'Filename',
                        id : 'fileName',
                        dataIndex : 'filename',
                        flex:1,
                        align:"left",
                        sortable: false,
                        hideable: false,
                        resizable: false,
                        editable : false
                   }
               ];
 

     this.store=UploadDocumentStore;
     this.callParent();
 
  }, 
  reloadGrid : function() {
    this.store.reload();
  },
  viewConfig: {
      emptyText: getText('queuegrid.pagingtoolbar.nodatamessage')
  }

});
```

Comment: "But, the Panel is not getting updated no matter what I do." <--- Which Panel? 'uploadDocumentGrid' or 'uploadPaperDocumentDialogPanel'? What do you mean by saying "not updated"?

Comment: uploadPaperDocumentDialogPanel has uploadDocumentGrid. uploadDocumentGrid is supposed get updated with values inserted into UploadDocumentStore. "not updated" means values are not visible immediately in the uploadDocumentGrid after insertion.

Comment: What about uploadDocumentGrid code? What if problem is there?

Comment: "var uploadDocumentGrid = Ext.define('DocumentGrid', {" <-- that is very strange syntax. It returns Ext.Base.. where do you need it?

Comment: Updated the code with uploadDocumentGrid code.

Comment: How do I refresh this uploadDocumentGrid to reflect the data on UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Arthur Rubens indicated, I started checking uploadDocumentGrid grid. And guess what that is where the problem was!

dataIndex field in uploadDocumentGrid for both columns was not matching with DocumentGridModel columns.
I updated uploadDocumentGrid as follows and values reflected on UI:

```
var uploadDocumentGrid = Ext.define('DocumentGrid', {
    extend:'Ext.grid.Panel'
    ,alias:'widget.documentGridId',
    width: 400,
    border:true,
    bodyPadding: 0,  // Don't want content to crunch against the borders
    title: 'Documents to be uploaded',
    id:'documentGridId',
    iconCls: 'icon-stipNote',
    columnLines: true     //INITCOMPONENT
    ,store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('uploadDocumentGridStore')
    ,initComponent : function() {
  
    this.columns= [
                    {
                         header : 'Document Type',
                         id : 'documentType',
                         dataIndex : 'documentType',
                         flex:1,
                         align:"left",
                         editable : false,
                        sortable: false,
                        hideable: false,
                        resizable: false,
                   }, {
                        header : 'Filename',
                        id : 'fileName',
                        dataIndex : 'fileName',
                        flex:1,
                        align:"left",
                        sortable: false,
                        hideable: false,
                        resizable: false,
                        editable : false
                   }
               ];
 

     this.store=UploadDocumentStore;
//finally call the super classes implementation
     this.callParent();
 
  }, 
  // RELOADGRID
  reloadGrid : function() {
    this.store.reload();
  },
  viewConfig: {
      emptyText: getText('queuegrid.pagingtoolbar.nodatamessage')
  }

});
```

I am still learning extjs. Thanks a lot for your help!